# ¿Cómo personalizar Swagger.json para cada usuario?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, configuración, swagger

Estuve realizando la documentación con Swagger (Swashbuckle NuGet package) de Webs API de un proyecto.

El problema ahora es que necesito personalizar(restringir y mostrar determinados servicios) estos Servicios dependiendo el usuario que ingrese al sistema.

**Ejemplo:**

**LISTA DE SERVICIOS**

```
AUTO
TREN
BICICLETA
MOTO
AVION
COLECTIVO
```

**JUAN INGRESÓ AL SISTEMA**

**SERVICIOS DISPONIBLES PARA JUAN**

```
AUTO 
TREN 
COLECTIVO
```

**MARÍA INGRESÓ AL SISTEMA**

**SERVICIOS DISPONIBLES PARA MARÍA**

```
MOTO 
AVIÓN
COLECTIVO
BICICLETA
```

**Swagger Config. actual:**

```
    using System.Web.Http;
using WebActivatorEx;
using Com.Deg.Web;
using Swashbuckle.Application;
using System;

[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]

namespace Com.Deg.Web
{
    public class SwaggerConfig
    {
        private static string GetXmlCommentsPath()
        {
            return String.Format(@"{0}\bin\Com.Deg.Web.xml", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
        }

        public static void Register()
        {
            var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .EnableSwagger("docs/{apiVersion}/swagger.json", c =>
                     {

                        c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "DegNet Web Services");

                        c.PrettyPrint();


                         c.GroupActionsBy(apiDesc =>
                         {
                             return apiDesc.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName.Replace("Api", "");
                         });


                        c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());

                        c.IgnoreObsoleteProperties();

                        })
        .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
        {
            });


        }
    }
}
```

**¿Cómo puedo realizar ese comportamiento dinámico de Swagger dependiendo el usuario en cuestión?**

Un saludo, estoy pendiente a cualquier duda con el tema planteado.

Comment: Hola. Te refieres a restringir los servicios al consumirlos o al visualizar la documentación swagger? Creo que lo que estás requiriendo es un Api Manager como `Api Management` de `Azure`

Comment: Mira este enlace a ver si te sirve. [How to hide swagger functionality from certain users](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/601)

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra buenos días,me refiero al visualizar la documentación swagger, que sea variable/dinámica (ver u ocultar determinados métodos) dependiendo el usuario en cuestión. Gracias por el link, ahora le doy una mirada. un saludo!